# Convert WAV file to FLAC in C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, encoding

I have a Wav file that I'm creating via the Microsoft Kinect that I'm saving to the desktop. I need to convert it to FLAC format so I can send it up to the Google Cloud to be processed from Speech2Text.

I haven't found any WAV to FLAC encoders in C#.

Is there any way to convert a WAV file to a FLAC file in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [***`LibFlac`***](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flac/files/flac-win/) (*sourceforge*). The `FLAC encoder` is an open-source C/C++ project. In order to use it in a C# application you have to use `PInvoke` to call its application programming interface `LibFlac.dll`. Checkout this blog post, that explore the processing of uncompressed audio data with the FLAC API in C#:

- [Encoding uncompressed audio with FLAC in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20150619011916/http://stoyanov.in/2010/01/08/encoding-uncompressed-audio-with-flac-in-c/)

Comment: ATTN Moderator: FYI The above link is empty.